# How to use Parse.query in a collection (Backbone like)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, fetch

I'm trying to fetch a `Parse.Collection` from a Class in parse.com. Everything works, but the fetch retuns an empty array (and the class in parse.com is not empty). I don't know exactly how to use `Parse.Query`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug further to narrow the error?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
Parse.initialize("XXX", "XXX");

var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "class-list": "listClasses",
  },

  initialize: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.loginView = new LoginView();

    // ----------------------------------------------------CLASS
    //                                                         |-----> Collection
    var ClassModel = Parse.Object.extend({
      className: "Classes"
    });
    this.classModel = new ClassModel();
    //                                                         |-----> Query
    var ClassQuery = new Parse.Query(ClassModel);
    ClassQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
        // results is an array of Parse.Object.
        return results;
      },

      error: function(error) {
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
      }
    });
    //                                                         |-----> Collection
    var ClassCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
      model: ClassModel,
      query: ClassQuery

    });
    this.classCollection = new ClassCollection();
    this.classCollection.fetch();
    //                                                         |-----> View
    var ListClassView = Parse.View.extend({
      initialize: function () {
        //this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
      },
      render: function () {
        this.$el.html(Handlebars.templates.class_list(this.collection));
        return this;
      }
    });
    this.listClassView = new ListClassView({
      collection: self.classCollection
    });
  },
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Parse.history.start();
```

Here is the info about the request on safari:
[image: request]
[image: response]

Comment: I'm not a backbone user, but, you can't 'return results' in the success block of your query and expect that to go anywhere.. perhaps store results on a property of the class in the success block?

Comment: Thanks, the `return` was only a testing I made and forgot to take it down. the same will happen without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `success:` handler you have the following line:

```
return results;
```

I'm not sure what you are expecting here, but what will happen is that you'll return the results to the Parse code that called your success handler. In fact the whole `find()` call there should be removed. The call to `fetch()` on the collection will call the underlying query for you.

From what I can see in the docs on [Collections](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#collections), if you want a Collection to be based on a Query you would do it as follows:

```
// UpperCamel for object we can use with new
var ClassModel = Parse.Object.extend("Classes");
// lowerCamel for a local variable
var classQuery = new Parse.Query(ClassModel);
// you don't call find() directly on the query, that'll mess things up

// UpperCamel for a collection definition
var ClassCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: ClassModel,
    query: classQuery
});

this.classCollection = new ClassCollection();

// at this point I would suggest connecting to the view first, then call fetch()

// ... ListClassView declaration skipped for brevity ...
this.listClassView = new ListClassView({
    collection: self.classCollection
});
this.classCollection.fetch();
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, I updated the file as you told me. (the return in the success was only a testing, i forgot to take it down, but its not the source of the problem). here is my code now: https://gist.github.com/otmezger/b42470ff2c9d48184401 won't work either. return is always empty.

Comment: code look ok to me cept for "," in line 40.. get a debugger on the line that does the fetch and find out what backbone an underscore are doing there

Comment: JavaScript object and array syntax allows for trailing "," e.g. `[1,2,3,] == [1,2,3]`, same for objects, makes it easier if you want to comment some out when they're each on their own line.

Comment: yes, the `,` in line 40 does not matter. it still don't work.

Comment: sorry, guys... I'm so stupid... there was a tiny error on the key... the code is ok and working.